# How to isolate client data on the same application using MySQL

Tags: mysql, schema, multi-tenant

I have made an application which has a `companies` table at the moment. It would work fine for a few clients (~100 companies, according to my scaling calculations). The application is a simple CRUD app accessed on the web using REST protocols. Very few (if none) concurrent transactions take place at the same time.

At the moment the `companies` table is the most independent table of all. All others like `employees`, `benefits`, `time_off`, etc. are related to each other via the `companies` table.

Someone suggested that I could use MySql's schemas to isolate one company from another, and clients would see the same exact app. Essentially, the moment I sign up a new company, a new schema would fire up and create the same tables as it has for any other company. How does this work? Could I have multiple schemas on the same database? I'm working with AWS RDS so I don't wish to pay for multiple databases here as the total size of the data even after half a year's use has not exceeded half a GB.

Comment: Do you currently have less than a dozen "tables" in a single "database" (aka "schema")?  And that is all in a single RDS instance?

Comment: @RickJames they're all in a single RDS instance, yes. But there are 35 tables in all, mainly for small things, but I have kept data as decoupled as possible.

Comment: 35?  OK, I was afraid it was hundreds -- split by `day` or `customer`.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Split by `customer` as in, every table gets a `customer_id` FK ?

Comment: For "isolation", consider one Database per customer.  But, if you get to the point of having thousands of customers, there may be problems.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL schema and database are synonymous: you use `CREATE DATABASE` or `CREATE SCHEMA` with equal effect. There's little physical isolation between schemas (databases), workload against one schema can potentially affect all schemas  on the same server. However, there is logical access isolation: you can allow certain user(s) access to a specific schema only using `GRANT ... ON schema.* TO ...`.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information or a link on the last part of your answer?

Comment: What kind of "more information"? It's a standard `GRANT` statement, described in the manual.

Comment: Splitting the companies across 100 databases (on the same RDS instance) will not cost much more disk space.  It will be 100 directories, each with a small number of tables.  Perhaps plus one database with information about the companies as a whole -- and accessible mostly to you, not them.